# Using XMLHttpRequest in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I started making this simple google chrome extension in javascript. And in the beginning of the code I have the following:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open(
    "GET",
    "http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/manga",
    true);

req.onreadystatechange(alert(req.readyState));
```

The value req.readyState comes to be 1, which means the required page has not been properly fetched. I'm a newbie to Javascript. What's the problem in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about something like this

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (request == null){
        alert("Unable to create request");
    }else{

        var url = "http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/manga";

        request.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
            if(request.readyState == 4)
            {
                LDResponse(request.responseText);
            }
        }

        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }

function LDResponse(response)
{
// do stuff with the response
}
```

Of course this is all assuming that they are giving you valid data back ie XML or json

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
req.onreadystatechange(alert(req.readyState));
```

`alert()` is being called straight away, which I'm sure isn't your intention. It seems that you want to wait for the `onreadystatechange` event to fire and then alert the `readyState`. If that's the case then try this:

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(req.readyState);
};
```

And don't forget `req.send(null)`!